# R :: dynamic sum across sequence of column names based on another column

Tags: r, sum, apply

Dataset:

*sumx is the output column required*

```
id  a1  a2  a3  a4  a5  mon sumx
x   1   2   1   0   1   2   4
y   2   3   1   0   3   4   3
z   0   0   2   2   0   1   4
```

Requirement: (**based on mon**):

```
for x: sumx = sum(a2 to a5)
for y: sumx = sum(a4 to a5)
for z: sumx = sum(a1 to a5)
```

Code I try to used gives an error stating that “*numerical expression has n elements: only the first used*”

```
df$sumx <- rowSums(df[c(paste("a", df$mon:5 , sep = ""))])
```

What I want to achieve is that based on the mon variable, the new variable created should sum from the sequence of variables (a1 to a5) starting from the respective number in mon to the last variable in sequence.

Comment: try: `apply(df, 1, function(x){
  a <- as.numeric(x[7]) 
  sum(as.numeric(x[a:6]))
})`

Answer (score 0):

You could try a simple for loop:

```
test.dat <- matrix(c(1,2,1,0,1,2,2,3,1,0,3,4,0,0,2,2,0,1), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
sum.vec <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(test.dat)){
  test.vec <- c()
  for (j in test.dat[i,6]:5){
    test.vec <- c(test.vec, test.dat[i,j])  
  }
  sum.vec[i] = sum(test.vec)
}
test.dat <- cbind(test.dat, sum.vec)
```